# Ionic Google Map Not Working In Device or -l Lab view but working prefect in Browser

Tags: google-maps, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-view, google-geolocation

i'm creating a nearby resturant using google map place api but when it fire on browser view it work prefect but not working in device or lab view i'm trying all thing searching all over the google github stackoverflow but nothing works please help me to solve this problem and save my life.
Thanking you in advance.

Problem is in geolocation feature policy i try everything but nothing solve my problem.
i thing there is something problem in my home.ts page code but i dont recognize what is actual problem.
[Error Shown During Lab View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDCTV.png)

```
Home.ts

import { Component, ViewChild ,ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Geolocation ,GeolocationOptions ,Geoposition ,PositionError } from '@ionic-native/geolocation'; 


declare var google;

@Component({
    selector: 'page-home',
    templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

@ViewChild('map') mapElement: ElementRef;
options : GeolocationOptions;
currentPos : Geoposition;
map: any;
places : Array<any> ;



constructor
(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    private geolocation : Geolocation,



    ) { } 



ionViewDidEnter(){
    this.getUserPosition();
}    




getUserPosition(){
    this.options = {
    enableHighAccuracy : false
    };
    this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.options).then((pos : Geoposition) => {

        this.currentPos = pos;     

        console.log(pos);
        this.addMap(pos.coords.latitude,pos.coords.longitude);

    },(err : PositionError)=>{
        //console.log("error : " + err.message);
    ;
    })
}

getRestaurants(latLng)
{
    var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(this.map);
    let request = {
        location : latLng,
        radius : 3000 ,
        types: ["restaurant"]
    };
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        service.nearbySearch(request,function(results,status){
            if(status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK)
            {
                resolve(results);    
            }else
            {
                reject(status);
            }

        }); 
    });

}

createMarker(place)
{
    let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: this.map,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    position: place.geometry.location
    });   
}  

addMap(lat,long){

    let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);

    let mapOptions = {
    center: latLng,
    zoom: 5,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }

    this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapElement.nativeElement, mapOptions);

    this.getRestaurants(latLng).then((results : Array<any>)=>{
        this.places = results;
        for(let i = 0 ;i < results.length ; i++)
        {
            this.createMarker(results[i]);
        }
    },(status)=>console.log(status));

    this.addMarker();
}


addMarker(){

    let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: this.map,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    position: this.map.getCenter()
    });

    let content = "<p>This is your current position !</p>";          
    let infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: content
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', () => {
    infoWindow.open(this.map, marker);
    });

}
}
```

Home.html

```
<ion-content>

  <div #map id="map"></div> 

  <div style="width : 100% ;height: 60%">
      <ion-list>

      <ion-item *ngFor="let place of places">
          <h4>{{place.name}}</h4>
          <p>{{place.vicinity}}</p>
          <p>Rating {{place.rating}}</p>
          <button ion-button clear item-end *ngIf="(place.opening_hours && !place.opening_hours.open_now)">CLOSED</button>
          <button ion-button clear item-end *ngIf="(place.opening_hours && place.opening_hours.open_now)">OPEN NOW</button>
      </ion-item>
      </ion-list>

  </div>


  </ion-content>


Index.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Shapekit</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="viewport-fit=cover, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
  <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">

  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/icon/logo.png">
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#4e8ef7">

  <!-- add to homescreen for ios -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">

  <!-- cordova.js required for cordova apps (remove if not needed) -->
  <script src="cordova.js"></script>

  <!-- un-comment this code to enable service worker
  <script>
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js')
        .then(() => console.log('service worker installed'))
        .catch(err => console.error('Error', err));
    }
  </script>-->

  <link href="build/main.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <script>
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js')
        .then(() => console.log('service worker installed'))
        .catch(err => console.error('Error', err));
    }
  </script>

</head>
<body>

  <!-- Ionic's root component and where the app will load -->
  <ion-app></ion-app>

  <!-- The polyfills js is generated during the build process -->
  <script src="build/polyfills.js"></script>

  <!-- The vendor js is generated during the build process
       It contains all of the dependencies in node_modules -->
  <script src="build/vendor.js"></script>

  <!-- The main bundle js is generated during the build process -->
  <script src="build/main.js"></script>


  <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=APIKEY&libraries=places"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `ionViewDidEnter`, consider to use **Platform** service:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({...})
export MyApp {
  constructor(public plt: Platform) {
    this.plt.ready().then((readySource) => {

      this.getUserPosition();

    });
  }
}
```

`ionViewDidEnter()` method is based on navigation. So to make sure that you actually run code when the device is ready, use Platform service.

Comment: not working its shows black white screen and error is: polyfills.js:2 Geolocation access has been blocked because of a Feature Policy applied to the current document.

Comment: error ->  polyfills.js:2 Geolocation access has been blocked because of a Feature Policy applied to the current document. See :goo.gl/EuHzyv for more details.

Comment: Does apply such changes work for you?. Is not, there is another library for maps, that is use by several companies.

https://leafletjs.com/.

Comment: Please describe the issue.

Comment: the problem is when i place this code   platform.ready().then(() => {

        
           this.getUserPosition(); there is map not show in lab -l or apk view but shows a gray page but not show map and in console error is: polyfills.js:2 Geolocation access has been blocked because of a Feature Policy applied to the current document.